# Notification when cant download artifact

Tags: nuget, slack, octopus-deploy, octopus

We have a scheduled release in Octopus that deploys the last known good release to Prod back to Prod.

However this has started failing because the artifact has fallen out of our retention policy - this we can fix by altering the retention policy.

The real issue is that when it failed no notifications were sent to the team because artifact collection happens before even the first step.

I have tested this with a dummy release that just has a single basic step and then a Slack Notification step for when it fails. However, we never get to the first step - let alone the slack step.

How can i hook on to this failure so that we know about these issues in future.

Comment: What version of Octopus are you using?
Also, by "artifact", do you mean package in the built-in feed?
Is your step set to "Run on failure" or "Run always"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow below steps to achieve the same

**Step 1)** Add Email Template step @ First : **to inform that Build is triggered**

There is a setting in that called : `Start Trigger` set it to `Run in parallel with the previous step` so email will be triggered while your artifacts are downloading

**Step 2)** Add Email Template step @ Last : **to inform that build failed**

Just change the setting `Run Condition` set it to : `Failure: only run when a previous step failed`

so when your deployment get fail, It will notify the same. You can add the `cause of failure` in email body using inbuilt variables also.